# How to select all columns in spark sql query in aggregation function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I am new to spark sql.

I have a query like this.

```
val highvalueresult = averageDF.select($"tagShortID", $"Timestamp", $"ListenerShortID", $"rootOrgID", $"subOrgID", $"RSSI_Weight_avg").groupBy("tagShortID", "Timestamp").agg(max($"RSSI_Weight_avg").alias("maxAvgValue"))
```

This prints only 3 columns.

```
tagShortID,Timestamp,maxAvgValue
```

But I want to display all the column along with this column.Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean all the columns? You are performing an aggregation so you would need an aggregation function for each column (i.e. for each pair of tagShortID,Timestamp there will be one line only). or are you talking about replicating the maxAvgValue for each row?

Comment: No my other columns like rootOrgID,subOrgID,ListenerShortID this is not showing in my select statement

Comment: what is your expected result? the maxAvgValue replicated to each line? some random value of rootOrgID of one of the lines with the pair? as it is now the number of lines in the source and target dataframes do not match. You handled this conversion for maxAvgValue but not for the rest.

Comment: I think the question is clear:  how does one perform an aggregation on all of the columns - *without specifying them explicitly*. Now - whether that were *possible* were not as clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative, usually good for your specific case is to use Window Functions, because it avoids the need to join with the original data:

```
import org.apache.spark.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("tagShortID", "Timestamp")

val result = averageDF.withColumn("maxAvgValue", max($"RSSI_Weight_avg").over(windowSpec))
```

You can find [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html) a good article explaining the Window Functions functionality in Spark.

Please note that it requires either Spark 2+ or a HiveContext in Spark versions 1.4 ~ 1.6.

Comment: Nice on :) I forgot about the Window functions

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple example with the column name you have

This is your `averageDF` dataframe with dummy data

```
+----------+---------+---------------+---------+--------+---------------+
|tagShortID|Timestamp|ListenerShortID|rootOrgID|subOrgID|RSSI_Weight_avg|
+----------+---------+---------------+---------+--------+---------------+
|         2|        2|              2|        2|       2|              2|
|         2|        2|              2|        2|       2|              2|
|         2|        2|              2|        2|       2|              2|
|         1|        1|              1|        1|       1|              1|
|         1|        1|              1|        1|       1|              1|
+----------+---------+---------------+---------+--------+---------------+
```

After you have a `groupby` and `aggravation`

```
val highvalueresult = averageDF.select($"tagShortID", $"Timestamp", $"ListenerShortID", $"rootOrgID", $"subOrgID", $"RSSI_Weight_avg").groupBy("tagShortID", "Timestamp").agg(max($"RSSI_Weight_avg").alias("maxAvgValue"))
```

This did not return all the columns you selected because after `groupby` and `aggregation` the only the used and result column are returned, As below

```
+----------+---------+-----------+
|tagShortID|Timestamp|maxAvgValue|
+----------+---------+-----------+
|         2|        2|          2|
|         1|        1|          1|
+----------+---------+-----------+
```

To get all the columns you need to join this two dataframes

```
averageDF.join(highvalueresult, Seq("tagShortID", "Timestamp"))
```

and the final result will be

```
+----------+---------+---------------+---------+--------+---------------+-----------+
|tagShortID|Timestamp|ListenerShortID|rootOrgID|subOrgID|RSSI_Weight_avg|maxAvgValue|
+----------+---------+---------------+---------+--------+---------------+-----------+
|         2|        2|              2|        2|       2|              2|          2|
|         2|        2|              2|        2|       2|              2|          2|
|         2|        2|              2|        2|       2|              2|          2|
|         1|        1|              1|        1|       1|              1|          1|
|         1|        1|              1|        1|       1|              1|          1|
+----------+---------+---------------+---------+--------+---------------+-----------+
```

I hope this clears your confusion.

Comment: But selecting multiple columns ?

Comment: Selecting columns does not matters after group by only the used and result column are returned. you need to join with original dataframe

Comment: I tried like this  val highvalueresult = averageDF.select($"tagShortID", $"Timestamp", $"ListenerShortID", $"rootOrgID", $"subOrgID", $"RSSI_Weight_avg").groupBy("tagShortID", "Timestamp").agg(max($"RSSI_Weight_avg").alias("maxAvgValue"))                     val t2 = averageDF.join(highvalueresult, Seq("rootOrgID","subOrgID","ListenerShortID"))

Comment: this is because ListenerShortID is not returned from aggregation

Comment: The returned columns in highvalueResult are (tagShortID,Timestamp,maxAvgValue)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149079/discussion-between-shankar-koirala-and-jessi-joseph).